# Download Artifactory Folder as an Archive using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, rest, artifactory

I'm trying to download an Artifactory folder as a tar.gz file using the PowerShell command line. In Bash, the following command does the job:

```
    curl -i -v -XGET -H 'X-JFrog-Art-Api:<my API key>' "https://artifactory.<myrepo.com>/path/to/files?archiveType=tar.gz" --output ./file_location/filename.tar.gz
```

In PowerShell, however, this doesn't seem to work:

```
    Invoke-RestMethod -uri "https://artifactory.<myrepo.com>/path/to/files?archiveType=tar.gz" -Method 'Get' -OutFile .\file_location\filename.tar.gz -H @{'X-JFrog-Art-Api' ='<my API key>';'Content-Type'='multipart/form-data'}
```

This operation creates filename.tar.gz, but the file is just a HTML file giving the directory structure rather than the actual files.

If I only want an individual file, I can use PowerShell to download files (not an archive) with:

```
    Invoke-RestMethod -uri "https://artifactory.<myrepo.com>/path/to/files/filename.xyz" -Method 'Get' -OutFile .\file_location\filename.xyz -H @{'X-JFrog-Art-Api' ='<my API key>';'Content-Type'='multipart/form-data'}
```

And filename.xyz is transferred to the local machine. So I'm a bit confused with why the tool to make an archive fails.

Comment: You might get better results with `Invoke-WebRequest`.

Comment: Any particular reason you're trying to send `'Content-Type' = 'multipart/form-data'`? That's invalid for a Get request. It may be your headers are sending back a "content-disposition; attachment" or something to initiate automatic download....as spicy.dll says invoke-webrequest may help - you can inspect the response headers.

Comment: Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 now come with `curl.exe`  (and `tar.exe`), so you can use your existing `curl` command - just make sure you specify the executable as `curl.exe`, not just `curl`, because the latter is a built-in _alias_ for PowerShell's [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) cmdlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out!

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://my-artifactory-server/artifactory/api/archive/download/path/to/some/folder?archiveType=zip -Method "Get" -Headers @{"Authorization"="Basic $my_artifactory_api_token"; 'Content-Type'='multipart/form-data'} -Outfile c:\destination_location\folder.zip
```

You need to add "api/archive/download" to the Uri, after the hostname.